# Does ABC implies Fermat's last theorem?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, popular-math

I read from the newspaper that Mochizuki's proof of the ABC conjecture implies the Fermat's last theorem. Is it true? I think it implies the proof only for large enough exponents?

Comment: It imlies FLT for exponents $\geq 6$. The argument can be found for example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Fermat.27s_Last_theorem).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130980/effect-of-abc-conjecture-on-fermats-last-theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Wikipedia there is a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for $n \geq 6$ given a "strong version" of the ABC conjecture, in which we assume for coprime $x, y, z$ where $x + y = z$ that $z < rad(xyz)^2$. It is as follows:

Letting $a^n + b^n = c^n$ and assuming WLOG that they are coprime, we have $$c^n < rad(a^n b^n c^n)^2 = rad((abc)^n)^2 = rad(abc)^2 \leq \; (abc)^2 < (c^3)^2 = c^6$$
And so any integer solution must have $n < 6$. Since individual proofs exist for the 3, 4, and 5 case, FLT follows.

Comment: This argument uses $abc< c^3$. Why is this true?  Why is it considered obvious?  What if $a>0$ and $b,c<0$?  Then the LHS is positive and the RHS is negative.

The proof also uses $c^n<c^6$ $\Rightarrow$ $n<6$.  Again it is using $c>0$.  Why can we assume this?

Comment: $c > a, b$ because $a,b,c > 0$ and $a^n + b^n = c^n$. As $c > a, b$, $abc < acc < ccc = c^3$. The reason we assume that $a,b,c > 0$ is because the statement of FLT says there are no **positive integer** solutions to $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for $n > 2$. So, I suppose, I should have included it in the list of assumptions next to coprimality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Actually the statement of FLT says there are no integer solutions.  Fermat's original statement said nothing about solutions being positive, he just said "numbers".  But I have come to realize the two statements are equivalent.  But in almost all textbooks it is stated with respect to integers.  Wikipedia and Encyclopedia Brittanica are exceptions, but if you google it you'll see most sources from the math world state it over $\mathbb Z$.  I think somebody should fix the wiki page actually to be in sync with the rest of the math world.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I would definitely be interested in the proof that the positive case implies the general case.

Comment: It actually turns out to be pretty simple to prove the equivalence.  It's obvious if $n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd and $a,b,c$ is a solution $a^n+b^n=c^n$ with $b<0$ then $a^n=c^n+(-b)^n$ gives a solution where $b>0$.  You can always rearrange things in this way to get all three $a,b,c >0$.  Just break it down into cases.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/abcConjecture.html), Fermat's Last Theorem for sufficiently large powers is a consequence of the abc conjecture.

So, if Mochizuki's proof is valid, then it would show this.