# On the Fermat-Taylor-Wiles proof from integers to polynomials, and Langlands program

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, langlands-program

What is known as the  Fermat's conjecture (or last theorem), proved by Taylor and Wiles (see [The Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem by R. Taylor and A. Wiles, 1995, Gerd Faltings, AMS notices](https://www.ams.org/notices/199507/faltings.pdf) or [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf), 2007, Darmon, Diamond, Taylor) states that the equation

$$ x^n+y^n =z^n$$

has no non-trivial integer solution ($xyz\neq 0$) for integer $n\ge 3$. The proof is notoriously difficult, and can be understood in full only by a few people. [Sir Andrew J. Wiles was awarded the Abel prize in 2016](http://www.abelprize.no/c67107/seksjon/vis.html?tid=67108&strukt_tid=67107).

The integers form a ring, and one may ask whether this conjecture applies in other rings. In the ring of polynomials with complex coefficients $\mathbb{C}[X]$, one may ask whether, for relatively prime polynomials $P(X)$, $Q(X)$ and $R(X)$

$$P^n(X)+Q^n(X)=R^n(X)$$

and it turns out that the above conjecture remains valid, and interestingly 5even surprisingly) only requires basic notions, and can be proved in 1-2 pages, using the [Wronskian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wronskian.html). This stems from the Mason's lemma (or [Mason–Stothers theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Stothers_theorem)): if  $A(X)$, $B(X)$ and $C(X)$ are non-trivial, relatively prime polynomials, and $A(X ) + B(X ) = C(X )$, then:

$$\max\{\deg (A), \deg(B), \deg(C)\} \le z(ABC) - 1,$$

where $z$ denotes the number of distinct zeroes.

Although a polynomial ring might seem more involved ([$\mathbb{Z}$ is difficult, polynomials are easy](http://www.math.ru.nl/~maubach/Slides/Saginaw_v01.pdf)), my understanding is that it inherits a notion of differentiation that is not present in integers, which in turn contrains the $\mathbb{C}[X]$'s structure so much that Fermat-Taylor-Wiles theorem becomes "almost trivial", since

$$\max\{\deg (P^n ), \deg (Q^n ), \deg (R^n )\} \le z((PQR)^n ) - 1,$$
thus

$$n\max\{\deg (P ), \deg (Q ), \deg (R )\} \le \deg (P )+ \deg (Q )+ \deg (R ) - 1.$$

A few days ago, the [Abel prize was awarded gain](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/20/science/robert-langlands-abel-prize-mathematics.html) to  [Robert P. Langlands, “for his visionary program connecting representation theory to number theory.”](http://www.abelprize.no/c73016/seksjon/vis.html?tid=73017&strukt_tid=73016), relating number theory, algebra and harmonic analysis.

How much is thisinteger/polynomial Fermat's conjecture simplification related to the  Langlands' program? More specifically:

- What are other examples of such drastic simplifications?
- Is this example really illustrative of Langlands' program

Comment: No, this is not really illustrative of [Langland's program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program). A drastic simplification is $n=1$, but then $x+y=z$ relates to the [abc-conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) $a+b=c$.

Comment: Isn't this  simplification a bit too drastic?

Comment: I personally fail to see how this is at all related to Langlands program.

Comment: No, this simplification is not too drastic. The equation $a+b=c$ is still a famous open question, the abc-conjecture. It roughly says, that not all of $a,b,c$ can be high powers of primes; so Fermat is not possible.

Comment: @Peter FLT follows from abc "immediately" in comparison to the long proof otherwise; even if we have to consider $n=3,4,5$ separately.

Comment: @LaurentDuval I am not sure whether a question should contain so many links, especially links to "person XY received the Abel-prize $\cdots$"

Comment: @DietrichBurde Assuming the abc-conjecture, is the proof actually "almost trivial" for $n\ge 6$ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, it is. Mazur wrote it down, it is something like $5$ lines trivial computation. That is, assuming the "explicit" abc-conjecture, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157932/does-abc-implies-fermats-last-theorem).

Comment: I wanted to provide some recent context that triggered my question, as my knowledge is shallow. I would be glad to remove some of them, or if someone else does, accepted